# How to sign data in PHP with HMAC using a PEM private key

Tags: java, php, hash, signature, hmac

I have seen a lot of posts about how to create a HMAC in PHP, but the used secret was always a simple string (eg. "secret"). What I need to do is create a HMAC with the secret being a private key, loaded for example from a file containing private key in PEM format. I have been unable to find any information on whether this is possible in PHP (using hash_hmac) or not.

### Usage

A HmacSHA256 signature using a private key is created in Java and I would like to recreate this signature in PHP (from my understanding using hash_hmac with sha256 hashing algorithm) with the same private key loaded from a file.

To clarify: 
the private key in this scenario is used as a shared secret key, meaning that two parties have the key. The message verification process consists of sending a HMAC with the message, calculated with the private key, while the recipient calculates HMAC with an identical private key and verifies it against the sent signature.

### Code

Java:

```
byte[] data = getDataForSignature();
PrivateKey key = getPrivateKey(); // loaded from a file
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
mac.init(key);
byte[] hmac = mac.doFinal(data);
// compare hmac with received signature bytes
```

PHP:

```
$key = openssl_pkey_get_private("private.key");
$sig = hash_hmac("sha256", $data, $key??, true);
```

Sample private key

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: What do you get for `key.getClass().getName()` in the Java code? `PrivateKey` is only the parent of the specific class below that. Can you show a sample key file as well? It seems `getPrivateKey` is an important function in this case.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes It's a sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl, I also added a sample key

Comment: Hmm, Java just uses the `byte[] secret = key.getEncoded();` as key (who'd have thunk :) ). So you are using the inner PKCS#8 encoding as key. That's certainly not good practice, but if you can encode a key with that *binary* DER encoding in PHP then you'd be golden.

Comment: I understand your last comment only a little bit, I would like to know what exactly is a bad practice there and what was that second part about encoding with binary DER but man its friday evening and I'm tired.

Comment: I'm at home with a cold, so I know what you mean :( You could use the command line option `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -in openssl_key.pem -inform pem -out openssl_key_pk8_enc.der -outform der` to convert the key to a binary key, then load this using binary input, and use that as key. I don't see an easy conversion within the openssl extensions of PHP.

Comment: It's bad practice because you are not using an RSA key (which consists of multiple integer values internally) as key for RSA operations (like signature generation). You are using the binary encoding of the key to perform MAC. This is an operation that should really not have been allowed by Java - it should at least check if it gets a `SecretKey` at the minimum.

Comment: Its hard to keep up with the edits...In reply to the bad practice, what do you mean by not using an RSA key, that's exactly what I use. Mac.init() takes a Key argument, the key I use is RSA private key. Also the method throws InvalidKeyException - if the given key is inappropriate for initializing this MAC (which it didn't throw for this key).

Comment: I am starting to get hold of this bad practice thing. The RSA key is not suitable for MAC hashing even thought it somehow works, or another way its actually not using the key data, but the whole key encoding which consists of more information than just the key data itself. By the way this implementation was inherited from a different project, but the client making the calls wasn't in PHP and apparently it also managed to create MACc with the RSA key. They used a public RSA key from the generated key pair, does that make a difference?

Comment: Using an RSA public key for MAC is worse; you'd expect the RSA public key to be - well - public. You should certainly not use that for MAC, it doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: Hmm, come to think of it, you could maybe just decode the base 64 inside the PEM and use that as key (for a quick fix answer).

Comment: In our context, all keys are "private", the public key was also "private". I just refer to them as private and public key because they are essentially asymmetric keys from a single RSA key pair. I could try it with the decoded base64 in PHP later.

Comment: Snap, doesn't work, it's a PKCS#1 encoded private key, not a PKCS#8 encoded private key... You really should just use 32 randomly generated bytes as key.

Comment: I somehow had the notion that it was PKCS#1, I just didn't know where I got that from so I was like meh, I guess it is PKCS#8 if he said so.

Comment: Note that PKCS#8 is *officially* BER encoded, and BER encoding is not canonical. I.e. different frameworks may encode the key (especially the length fields) slightly differently, leading to a slightly different key. Usually DER will be used, but you could not blame an implementation to use a slightly different length format or different order in a ASN.1 SET. Obviously slightly different keys lead to completely different authentication tags for HMAC.

Comment: A PKI digital signature is not a HMAC like you're attempting. `openssl_sign(with private key)` and `openssl_verify(with public key)` and the functions to use in PHP with compatible public/private key pairs. An RSA key shouldn't really be used in a HMAC function.

Answer (score 2):

Usually a private key is used to perform *signature generation* which is the asymmetric equivalent to creating a MAC with a symmetric secret key.

Note that a HMAC key can consist of any binary string, so in principle it would be possible to use HMAC with a binary encoded private key. That said, it doesn't make sense to use a asymmetric private key for HMAC. Only the person holding the private key would be able to verify the resulting authentication tag. In comparison, digital signatures can be verified using the public key of the key pair.

---

Now if you have a *secret* key that was used within Java then you need to create the same (binary) `key` parameter for the PHP `hash_hmac` function.

Comment: First off, thank you for answering. To clarify, the private key in this scenario is used as a shared secret key, meaning that two parties have the key. The message verification process consists of sending a HMAC with the message, calculated with the private key, while the recipient calculates HMAC with an identical private key and verifies it against the sent signature. So while your answer is not wrong, it doesn't answer my question, how to use a private key stored in file in conjunction with PHP hash_hmac function to create an identical signature to one made in Java with Mac interface.

Comment: It will be hard to answer that without you showing both the Java code and what you tried for PHP.

Comment: I will fix that up soon.