# How to create a valid JWT in PHP using RSA256

Tags: php, jwt

I have been having similar difficulties to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35314629/how-to-sign-data-in-php-with-hmac-using-a-pem-private-key). I need to create a JWT in php. I have the following code:

```
define('RSA_PRIVATE', 'MIICXAIB......EWxOf9o=');

$payload = json_encode([
    'sub' => 'username',
    'email' => 'john@example.com',
    'given_name' => 'John',
    'family_name' => 'Example',
    'iat' => time(),
    'nonce' => '12345'
]);


$header = json_encode([
    'typ' => 'JWT',
    'alg' => 'RS256'
]);

$base64UrlHeader = base64UrlEncode($header);
$base64UrlPayload = base64UrlEncode($payload);
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', "$base64UrlHeader.$base64UrlPayload", RSA_PRIVATE, true);                                

$base64UrlSignature = base64UrlEncode($signature);
$jwt = "$base64UrlHeader.$base64UrlPayload.$base64UrlSignature";

echo($jwt);


function base64UrlEncode($text)
{
    return str_replace(
        ['+', '/', '='],
        ['-', '_', ''],
        base64_encode($text)
    );
}
```

Whenever I attempt to validate with the third party that needs my JWT it comes back with a message telling me

Signature validation failed: rsa signature did not match

When I attempt to validate using the [JWT debugger](https://jwt.io/), it too says it is invalid.

Am I missing something here? Like the previous question I have only ever seen examples where people are using small secrets and not private RSA keys.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php

Comment: @M.SallarRabiei it doesn't make much sense to suggest the same question as duplicate target that the OP mentioned in his post. Obviously he read it already and it did not answer his question.

Comment: and generally the linked question seems to be a sort of XY-problem with the conclusion "it doesn't make sense to use a asymmetric private key for HMAC" in the answer, but not really a solution for this question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the answer by @Michal Trojanowski I went on to use openssl_sign. However this did not work when I had the key as a variable in my code. Instead, following the example on the [php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php) I managed to get it to work using the following adjustment:

```
$private_key = openssl_pkey_get_private("file:///path.to/jwtRS256.key");

openssl_sign(
    "$base64UrlHeader.$base64UrlPayload",
    $signature,
    $private_key,
    "sha256WithRSAEncryption"
);

openssl_free_key($private_key);

$base64UrlSignature = zd_base64UrlEncode($signature);
$jwt = "$base64UrlHeader.$base64UrlPayload.$base64UrlSignature";
```

Answer (score 1):

You chose `RS256` as the signature algorithm, which is an asymmetrical signing algorithm and you create the signature with a HMAC function, which is a symmetrical signing algorithm.

If you want to stick to `RS256` try to follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43313973/1712294

If you want to stick with a symmetrical algorithm change the data in your header to

```php
$header = json_encode([
    'typ' => 'JWT',
    'alg' => 'HS256'
]);
```

The recommended way is to go with an asymmetrical algorithm.

Comment: the question title says that OP wants RS256 and the recommended way IMO is to use a proper [JWT library](https://jwt.io/#libraries-io)

Comment: The third party requires RS256 so I cannot use HS256

Answer (score 0):

You can generate JWT in PHP using RSA256

```
function base64url_encode($data){
    return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '=');
}

function generateToken(){
    $privateKey = file_get_contents('private.pem');

    $base64UrlHeader = base64url_encode(
        json_encode(
            array(
                'typ' => 'JWT',
                'alg' => 'RS256'
            )
        )
    );

    $now = time();
    $base64UrlPayload = base64url_encode(
        json_encode(
            array(
                "sub" => "1",
                "exp" => $now + 3600,
                "iat" => $now
            )
        )
    );

    openssl_sign(
        $base64UrlHeader.".".$base64UrlPayload,
        $RSA256,
        $privateKey,
        "sha256WithRSAEncryption"
    );

    $keyRSA256 = base64url_encode($RSA256);
    $jwt = $base64UrlHeader . "." . $base64UrlPayload . "." . $keyRSA256;

    return json_encode(array('status' => true, 'code' => 200, 'data' => $jwt));
}
```